# Как запустить стандартный MVC-проект вне среды Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день!

Только начинаю изучать ASP.NET MVС и я не могу понять, во что компилируется проект MVC и как его потом запустить вне среды Visual Studio на loaclhost'е (Для примера, проекты Console App или WinForms в конечном итоге превращаются в exe-файл, который можно запустить, а что является конечным файлом для MVC - не знаю). Я знаю, что по сути должна из браузера открываться html-страница `index`. Но, как я понимаю, нужен какой-то локальный сервер.

Я понимаю, что вопрос может вам показаться глупым, но я начинающий и не смог найти информацию в интернете.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

К примеру, для запуска ASP.NET MVС проекта вне среды разработки вам понадобится:

- Сервер IIS с необходимой платформой .NET Framework
- Скомпилированный проект ASP.NET MVС

Почитать для ознакомления:

- [Веб-серверы в Visual Studio для веб-проектов ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/58wxa9w5(v=vs.120).aspx)
- [Публикация приложения (Среда публикации и составные части приложения)](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/13.1.php)
- [Пошаговое руководство. Настройка приложений ASP.NET в IIS 7.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb763174(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Пошаговое руководство. Развертывание проекта веб-сайта с помощью средства публикации веб-сайтов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Развертывание веб-сайта с помощью IIS](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/sites/level3/3_2.php)
- [Публикация приложения (Публикация на IIS)](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/20.1.php)
- [Публикация на веб-сервере IIS](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/13.2.php)

Информации достаточно много, прикрепил вам для ознакомления несколько ссылок. Ну и в качестве *бонусной* ссылки рекомендую к ознакомлению вот эту:

- [Запуск ASP.NET-приложений на платформе Linux](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-Mono_10/)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а как же дать права на директории, в которой будет лежать сайт? А установка новых компонент, самой IIS к примеру. Хотя, возможно и избыточны, но лишними уж точно не будут :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, для установки компонент в системе нужны права администратора. А на паку дать права пользователю IUSR/IIS_IUSRS

Comment: @DenisBubnov а только ли на IIS можно запускать опубликованный проект ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @DenisBubnov На сайте metanit подробно расписано, как опубликовать приложение на IIS. Попробую данный способ. Отпишусь сюда, когда опробую его. Спасибо.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, по поводу запуска, скажем так, дефолтный вариант запуска - это IIS, ну, естественно на Windows. Но, если у вас Linux-подобная система, то можно на Apache с дополнительными плагинами и Mono, но это как говорится - танцы с бубном и там не все так просто.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, откройте третью ссылку [Пошаговое руководство. Настройка приложений ASP.NET в IIS 7.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb763174(v=vs.100).aspx) найдите текст: *Административные разрешения на локальном компьютере.*. А еще, в самом начале, я вам написал: *Хотя, возможно и избыточны, но лишними уж точно не будут*

Comment: @DenisBubnov вы видите разницу между IIS и IIS Express? Первый - компонент винды, второй - переносимая программа, которую можно использовать вообще без установки в систему.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, вы правы, как-то я не понял намека про *компоненты для IIS Express*... Внес правку в ответ, добавил пояснения к пункту про права админа и убрал лишнее слово *Express*, спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: @DenisBubnov я воспользовался функцией Publish(опубликовать) и разместил все файлы в папку C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite. Использовал [данную статью](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/13.2.php). Но `Destination URL` мне не предлагали выбирать (у меня VS 2015). Теперь я не знаю, какой url у моего сайта. Сам IIS работает. Где можно изменить URL?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, откройте IIS, взгляните, на каком порту у вас сайт развернут, скорее всего это 80 порт, и если вы напишете *http://localhost* то перейдете на свой сайт, ну, либо посмотрите в привязки для начала, там можно нажать на ссылку справа и открыть сайт в браузере, пункт *Обзор веб-сайта*. А *Destination URL* - это URL, который будет открыт после публикации, его всегда можно изменить в настройках публикации

Comment: @DenisBubnov на 80 порту. И я уже пробовал localhost прописывать, он мне открывает стандартную страницу с рекламой IIS. В общем, уже нашел. http://localhost/site_name/. Спасибо! Будем дальше разбираться)

Answer (score 6):

Вам понадобятся:

1. Статические файлы (обычно это папки Content, Scripts и Views - но могут быть любые)
2. Папка bin (тот самый результат компиляции)
3. Файл web.config

Также понадобятся сервер IIS. Это компонент винды, ставится (на восьмерке, в других виндах может называться по-другому) через "Панель управления" - "Программы и компоненты"  - "Включение и отключение компонентов Windows". На серверных виндах нужна роль "Веб-сервер" или "Сервер приложений", точно не помню.

Все эти файлы надо перенести в папку c:\inetpub, ее подпапку - или в любое другое место.

- Если вы копировали файлы в корень inetpub - ваш сайт уже может работать.
- Если вы создали вложенную папку - вам надо зайти в настройки IIS, найти там эту папку, нажать на нее правой кнопкой и выбрать пункт "Преобразовать в приложение".
- Если вы положили файлу куда-то еще, вам надо создать сайт или приложение, и указать для него виртуальный и физический пути (виртуальный путь - это адрес сайта, физический - это где лежат его файлы).

Имеется способ автоматически скопировать в выходную папку дерево необходимых веб-серверу файлов, чтобы не искать их вручную. Для этого надо построить проект из командной строки через msbuild с ключами "/t:PipelineCopyAllFilesToOneFolderForMsdeploy /p:Configuration=Release /p:WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder=путь\к\выходной\папке"

Также можно получить архив с этими файлами, пригодный для развертывания через msdeploy (службу управления IIS) - для этого надо указать ключи "/t:Package /p:Configuration=Release /p:PackageLocation=путь\к\выходной\папке"

Кроме того, если просто собрать проект с ключом "/t:Package" - то все файлы в одном месте можно будет найти по пути obj*\Package\PackageTmp

Также набор файлов для развертывания можно получить через саму студию, нажав на проект правой кнопкой и выбрав пункт "Публикация..." ("Publish...")

Answer (score 3):

Исходный код компилируется в исполняемые файлы. Вы можете сами посмотреть, что получится в итоге, если "опубликуете" проект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как это веб-приложение, то для его работы нужен сервер. VS использует IIS сервер, так что и вы можете попробовать развернуть проект на IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Здравтсвуйте!

Все веб приложения ASP.NET работают на веб сервере. В среде Windows это IIS, веб сервер от Microsoft. Как правило, он не установлен на обычных компьютерах пользователей, но его можно в любой момент добавить из компонетов Windows.

После того как он будет установлен на нужном компьютере, который будет выступать в роли веб сервера, сервер нужно будет сконфигурировать, создать в нем сайт, и затем опубликовать проект.

Вот тут почитайте о найстройке IIS
https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/sites/level3/3_1.php